# Owl Carousel returning errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm trying to install Owl Carousel 2 in my website, for the first time using this, and following all the insctructions I'm still having some problems.

After import all files:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The badass man alive</title>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Adding the demo javascript code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
  });
});
```

And trying to load the example file:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
   <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
   <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
   <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
   <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
   <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
   <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
</div>
```

The console returns this:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: a(...).find(...).andSelf is not a function TypeError: a(...).find(...).andSelf is not a function
    at c.<anonymous> (file:///.../assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js:2:7592)
    at HTMLDivElement.e (file:///.../assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:3655)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (file:///.../assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (file:///.../assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8342)
    at Object.trigger (file:///.../assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:5808)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (file:///.../assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:6318)
    at Function.each (file:///.../assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:2815)
    at r.fn.init.each (file:///.../assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:1003)
    at r.fn.init.trigger (file:///.../assets/vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:6294)
    at e.trigger (file:///.../assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js:1:22366) undefined
Uncaught TypeError: a(...).find(...).andSelf is not a function(…)
```

And I have no ideia why it's returning this error.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is in absence of andSelf function in older versions of jQuery. Try to add to your .js file the following

```
$.fn.andSelf = function() {
  return this.addBack.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip. My problem was solved. Good works.

Answer (score 5):

.andSelf() was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0. .addBack() should be used instead from jQuery 1.8 onward.

So for a quick and dirty fix, in your **owl.caorusel.min.js** file, just replace the word "**andSelf**" with "**addBack**", and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I tried using older version of jQuery and it worked just fine. Try using older version of jQuery.